# Can I use value in nth-child to invoke the id of the element?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="tiles blue tile-group four-wide" id="tile_system" 
style="border-    color:#07caca;>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="1" id="1">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" /></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="2" id="2">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" id="1"/></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="3" id="3">
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="4" id="4">
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="5" id="5">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" id="1"/></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="6" id="6">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" id="1"/></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="7" id="7">
        <div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="8" id="8">
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="9" id="9"> 
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" id = "changemydata" data-speed="750"
 data-delay="3000"" value="10" id="10"> 
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="11" id="11">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" /></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="12" id="12">
    <a href="#"><div><img src="images/r1.gif" class="food-l" /></div></a>
    <div><img src="images/r2.gif" class="food-l"id="2"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="13" id="13">
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="14" id="14">
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="15" id="15">   
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>
<div class="live-tile" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000" value="16" id="16">   
        <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
    <div><img src="images/r3.gif" class="l-other"/></div>
</div>

</div>
 <script>

 $(window).load(function() {
$('.live-tile').click(function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if ( a%2 == 0)
    {   var b = a + 1;
        $("#live-tile :nth-child(" + a + ")").removeClass('live-tile').addClass('live-tile two-wide');
        $("#live-tile :nth-child(" + b + ")").slideUp(1000);
    }
    else
    {   var c = a - 1;
        $("#live-tile :nth-child(" + a + ")").removeClass('live-tile').addClass('live-tile two-wide');
        $("#live-tile :nth-child(" + c + ")").slideUp(1000);
    }
    });
```

});
I have to use this function to replace the class accordingly their even and odd status. I have been working on it for a very long time and I'm stuck.what should I do?the function hides the tile just next one or previous one.

Comment: May I ask, out of curiosity, what is the `c` variable used for after this code?

Comment: I would use it in $('#' + c).function

Comment: ... Why? If you have `$("#system :nth-child("+a+")")`, then you already have a jQuery object. You do not need to get its ID just to select it again...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you need to interpolate the `a` variable:

```
var c = $("#system :nth-child("+a+")").attr("id");
```

But you'd be much better off with [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

```
var c = document.getElementById('system').children[this.value].id;
```

(Small side-note: The vanilla JS version is the same as `"#selector>:nth-child("+a+")"`, which is slightly different from your original jQuery in that it only looks at the direct child nodes, whereas your jQuery will return any node down the line that happens to be the a'th child of its parent. I believe you actually wanted to use the `>` combinator anyway)

Comment: Interesting http://vanilla-js.com/ claims Stack Overflow uses vanilla JS, while Stack Overflow actually uses jQuery

Comment: A descendant combinator is used in the selector not  a child combinator so the plain js version is not equivalent.

Comment: @JanDvorak How true. But technically all websites use vanilla JS. After all, the `+` operator is vanilla JS ;)

Comment: @Musa True, but it's highly likely that a child combinator was intended.

Comment: @Kolink the inequality should probably be mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Selectors doesn't use variables, you have to use the value of the variable in the string:

```
var c = $("#system :nth-child(" + a + ")").attr('id');
```

#### Edit:

If the value that you are getting could be invalid, you should verify it before using it in the selector. For example:

```
$("#inp").blur(function () {
  var a = $(this).val();
  if (/^\d+$/.test(a)) {
    var c = $("#system :nth-child(" + a + ")").attr('id');
    alert(c);
  } else {
    alert("No number entered");
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EYvGE/

Also, instead of getting the element to get the the id to use to get the element, just get the element. Instead of:

```
var c = $("#system :nth-child(" + a + ")").attr('id');
var d = $("#" + c);
```

just do:

```
var d = $("#system :nth-child(" + a + ")");
```

Comment: Now It is showing  the uncaught error syntex error unrecognized expression : nth-child in jquery.min.1.9.1 file

Comment: @user2152295: Then it looks like you have to verify the value before using it in the selector. I added an example above.